# can't find Pyodbc Microsoft Access driver

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

It seems that even though I have the driver present pyodbc can't find it.

[image]

```
import pyodbc
import os
p = r'C:\Users\jmarshall\source\Bandz_Dev\Apps\ms tech support database.accdb'
driver='{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
conn_string=f'Driver={driver};DBQ={p}'
assert os.path.exists(p), True
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver)
```

[image]

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?  It looks like it has to be a `pyodbc` thing as far as recognizing the drivers.

Comment: Is your Python 32-bit?  Your screen capture does not show the `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}` driver for 32-bit.

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: @HansUp - your totally right.  I'm on the 32bit version without realizing.... so stupid.

Comment: @GordThompson  - I did not know about that check for drivers.  Would have saved me so much time.  Will hold onto that.